# Firebase query to fetch specific users by their user IDs in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database structure like this

```
"Users": {
    "ghjghjFc1S3KO0y8yJwORdfgret": {   //user ID
              "name": "John" 
    }

    "3uqWZJRFc1S3KO0y8yJwORTMtWC2": {   //user ID
              "name": "Smith"
    }

    "4SrHGdRFc1S8KO0y8yJwORTMtQAR": {   //user ID
              "name": "Alan"
    }

    "5fvxhaxFc1S8Kf0ygyJwORyMtFdy": {   //user ID
              "name": "Ben"
    }

}
```

I have an array: usersToRetreive = ["5fvxhaxFc1S8Kf0ygyJwORyMtFdy", "3uqWZJRFc1S3KO0y8yJwORTMtWC2"]

and I want to retrieve only those users whose userID is given in the array 'usersToRetreive'

Does firebase support this type of query? if yes then how can I make this query in swift?

Comment: Maybe start with googling for example, before adding new question?

Comment: I didn' find the answer that's why I am posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Firebase does support this type of query. You have to use the orderByChild() method on the database reference. This Firebase Youtube video goes through how to do this.

[Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database - The Firebase Database For SQL Developers #4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs)

Comment: Thanks Philip for sharing this video it is very much helpful but I could not find the solution of my problem. I just want to give array of user IDs to firebase and it give me back the filtered users. I want to avoid long loop on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question you are trying to fetch specfic users all informations which are inside your Arraylist given by their ID number.

First of all this kind of data map structure is not competible with firebase. There is no specific easy way to do that. It would be very expensive if you fetch all data then search locally. You can dublicate the information of the users where it is written their id numbers if you use this way .. Becouse 1 million character will cost around 2MB .. The important thing in Firebase is How you use the TRAFFIC. NOT MEMORY .
You can alternatively use Firebase BIGDATA queries .

Answer (score -2):

Just do a for loop over your array and fetch each user separately, don't see what the big problem is..

Comment: So if there are 1000 IDs in that array then it will call firebase 1000 times to fetch that users. Is that good practice ?

Comment: Yes that's fine. If you're concerned then just fetch all the users and filter the list client-side.

Comment: This is the simplest but bad way (imagine if users are in millions or array contains thousands of IDs). I was thinking that there should be an efficient way to do this.